# Openshift secure delete using "oc delete secret"

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, etcd, okd

I have been asked by security auditors to explain the underlying process of `oc delete secret` What they want to establish is that the secret is not recoverable by forensics tools for example, once deleted.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of layers you would have to peel in order to do a thorough assessment/audit. Start by looking at the calls performed by the `oc` CLI which underneath should be sending a request to the [DELETE secret endpoint on the API Server](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#delete-secret-v1-core).

Ultimately, In Kubernetes, the delete operation will come down to deleting a key from the etcd datastore as seen [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/b378b175606aded0d3b38e6ab72ea308eb279e9b/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/storage/etcd3/store.go#L221). You can further dig into the [etcd Go API](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/clientv3/op.go#L231) and etcd internals in order to determine how the deletion is performed across cluster nodes on commit, and determining whether a forensics tool would be able to pry into the storage blocks on disk.

Also, ensure Pods that mount the secrets are not writing the data to disk or to logs.